# force mandrill API send mails, not django with smtp

Tags: django, email, mailchimp, mandrill

Can django send data to Mandrill, so it will take care about sending mails?
When i do with SMTP, I need to wait to page send mails(over 1000 mails).

I use django framework.

Is this possible?

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/sirpengi/django-mandrill

Comment: i tried this, but still got delay when sending, is this expected?

Comment: It can definitely take some time to send 1000+ emails. I run an app that sends emails through SendGrid synchronously, and I see a response time of probably 6 - 8 seconds to send 30k+ emails, all BCCs.

Comment: For 5 emails, i need to wait 5 seconds :/ that is proble, it is too long for only 5 mails, but i loop, i think that can be problem.

Comment: Yes, that is definitely a long time to wait. Is the content unique per email? If not, I would add the recipients as BCCs and send 1 email. If you're doing some kind of personalization, see if Mandrill has an API for that instead of doing it in your Python code. SendGrid for example has a replacement API, where I can pass in delimiters to be replaced as key/value pairs.

Comment: I did with bcc, and i needed to hide mails from other, so one user only sees his mail. Thanks.

Comment: BCC recipients are unaware of other BCC recipients automatically.

Comment: In mandrill they se others by default, need to pass header to make it hide.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it with bcc and **preserve recipients**:

```
msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, plain_body, from_email, emails, headers={'X-MC-PreserveRecipients': False})
msg.attach_alternative(html_body, "text/html")
msg.send()
```